# Docker: приложение на питоне не доступно другим микросервисам

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose

У нас есть приложение на питоне, которое выглядит очень просто: просто контроллер, который выдаёт по запросу JSON.

Лежит оно здесь:
https://github.com/NikaGolybeva/smt

Контроллер:

```
#!flask/bin/python
from flask import Flask, jsonify

app = Flask(__name__)

tasks = [
    {
        'id': 1,
        'title': u'Buy groceries',
        'description': u'Milk, Cheese, Pizza, Fruit, Tylenol',
        'done': False
    },
    {
        'id': 2,
        'title': u'Learn Python',
        'description': u'Need to find a good Python tutorial on the web',
        'done': False
    }
]

from flask import abort


@app.route('/test', methods=['GET'])
def get_tasks():
    return jsonify({'tasks': tasks})

@app.route('/test/<int:task_id>', methods=['GET'])
def get_task(task_id):
    task = list(filter(lambda t: t['id'] == task_id, tasks))
    if len(task) == 0:
        abort(404)
    return jsonify({'task': task[0]})



if __name__ == '__main__':
    app.run(debug=True)
```

Dockerfile:

```
FROM python:3.7
EXPOSE 5000
ADD run.py /
RUN pip install pystrich
RUN pip install flask
CMD [ "python", "./run.py" ]
```

Запускаем приложение при помощи docker на порту 5000:

```
v-chernyshov@v-chernyshov:~/IdeaProjects/smt$ docker build -t smt .

...

v-chernyshov@v-chernyshov:~/IdeaProjects/smt$ docker run -p 5000:5000 smt
 * Serving Flask app "run" (lazy loading)
 * Environment: production
   WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
   Use a production WSGI server instead.
 * Debug mode: on
 * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
 * Restarting with stat
 * Debugger is active!
 * Debugger PIN: 309-988-075
```

Ожидается, что при запросе по адресу `http://localhost:5000/test/1` приложение вернёт JSON. Но по факту, сервис не доступен.

Окей. Вариант 2.

Добавляем приложение в docker-compose и собираем на виртуальном сервере. Сам файл выглядит так:

```
services:
  web:
    image: account/front:0.0.1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 80:3000
  back:
    image: account/back:0.0.3
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 8099:8099
  smth:
    image: nikagolybeva/smth:0.0.1
    restart: on-failure
    ports:
      - 5000:5000
```

Есть back на java, есть smth на python. Я написал метод, который раз в минуту пытается дёрнуть контроллер приложения на питоне по REST:

```
@Scheduled(initialDelay = 1000L, fixedDelay = 60000L)
public void testPython() {
    String url = "http://smth:5000/test/1";
    log.info("testing python, url: {}", url);
    PythonTestDto pythonTestDto = restTemplate.getForObject(url, PythonTestDto.class);
    String result = "";
    try {
        result = new ObjectMapper().writeValueAsString(pythonTestDto);
    } catch (JsonProcessingException e) {
        e.getMessage();
    }
    log.info("response: {}", result);
}
```

Запускаем приложения через docker-compose.

back и message поднимаются на своих портах:

```
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Serving Flask app "run" (lazy loading)
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Environment: production
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |    WARNING: This is a development server. Do not use it in a production deployment.
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |    Use a production WSGI server instead.
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Debug mode: on
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Running on http://127.0.0.1:5000/ (Press CTRL+C to quit)
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Restarting with stat
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Debugger is active!
smth_1_f8c6211ef46d |  * Debugger PIN: 769-002-661

...

back_1_9622a732ea20 | 2019-09-26 08:16:31.725  INFO 1 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8099 (http) with context path ''
```

Пингуем smth из back:

```
root@kvm1:/home/xpendence/docker# docker-compose exec back ping smth
PING smth (172.21.0.3): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=0 ttl=64 time=0.396 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=1 ttl=64 time=0.142 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=2 ttl=64 time=0.175 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=3 ttl=64 time=0.195 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=4 ttl=64 time=0.113 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=5 ttl=64 time=0.127 ms
64 bytes from 172.21.0.3: seq=6 ttl=64 time=0.521 ms
^C
--- smth ping statistics ---
7 packets transmitted, 7 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 0.113/0.238/0.521 ms
```

При этом, попытка микросервиса back дёрнуть smth по REST неудачна:

```
back_1_9622a732ea20 | org.springframework.web.client.ResourceAccessException: I/O error on GET request for "http://smth:5000/test/1": Connection refused (Connection refused); nested exception is java.net.ConnectException: Connection refused (Connection refused)
```

Коллеги, подскажите, что не так. Подозрение, что проблема всё-таки в том, как написан REST-контроллер на питоне. Потому что другие микросервисы при таких настройках и попытках достучаться до них доступны по REST.

Comment: Вы почему-то запускаете Flask на IP-адресе 127.0.0.1, который за пределами локальной сети контейнера очевидно недоступен

Comment: А ещё внимательно прочитайте WARNING

Comment: Есть конкретное решение для человека, который не понимает питон?

Comment: Неправильное — запускать Flask на IP-адресе 0.0.0.0, правильное — поставить gunicorn и запускать Flask через него тоже на IP-адресе 0.0.0.0 (или uwsgi, но он сложнее)

Comment: Собственно, в первой ссылке в гугле по запросу «flask docker» как раз запускают gunicorn https://habr.com/ru/post/353234/

Comment: Спасибо. Можете оформить свои комментарии в ответ, чтобы я мог принять его как решение?